# I want to check for a collision in pygame. I want so when my player hits the wall he stops

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, collision-detection, collision

I'm a begginer and I some stuff about Pygame so I decided t otry doing sothing by myself to practice my skills. I already know the colliderect but I don't know how exactly do you check. I'm making a copy of Adventure. I might sound so confucing. Sorry for that. Here is the code that i have right now:

```
import pygame
import sys
from pygame.locals import *

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

pygame.init()

pygame.display.set_caption("Neverout")
player = pygame.image.load("player.png")

green = (164, 164, 164)

WINDOW_SIZE = (1200, 700)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(WINDOW_SIZE, 0, 32)

wall_rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 1200, 50)
wall_rect2 = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 50, 1200)
wall_rect3 = pygame.Rect(50, 650, 450, 50)
wall_rect4 = pygame.Rect(1150, 0, 50, 700)
wall_rect5 = pygame.Rect(700, 650, 750, 50)

player_pos = [385, 385]

up = False
down = False
right = False
left = False

while True:

    screen.blit(player, player_pos)

    if left is True:
        player_pos[0] -= 8
    if right is True:
        player_pos[0] += 8
    if up is True:
        player_pos[1] -= 8
    if down is True:
        player_pos[1] += 8

    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                left = True
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                right = True
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                up = True
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                down = True

        elif event.type == KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                left = False
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                right = False
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                up = False
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                down = False

        elif event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    pygame.display.update()
    screen.fill(green)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (230, 218, 0), wall_rect)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (230, 218, 0), wall_rect2)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (230, 218, 0), wall_rect3)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (230, 218, 0), wall_rect4)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (230, 218, 0), wall_rect5)
    clock.tick(60)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a list of walls:

```py
wall_list = [wall_rect, wall_rect2, wall_rect3, wall_rect4, wall_rect5]
```

Store the position of the player before you move the player:

```py
prev_pos = player_pos[:]
```

Get the current rectangle ([`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html)) after the player is moved:

```py
plyer_rect = player.get_rect(topleft = player_pos)
```

Use [`colliderect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.colliderect) to evaluate if the `plyer_rect` intersects [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) rectangle of `wall_list`. If the player hits a wall then undo the movement:

```py
if any(plyer_rect.colliderect(w) for w in wall_list):
    player_pos = prev_pos
```

Furthermore I recommend to use [`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed) rather the the key events for the movement of the player:

```py
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
    player_pos[0] -= 8
if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
    player_pos[0] += 8
if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
    player_pos[1] -= 8
if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
    player_pos[1] += 8
```

Complete example:

```py
import pygame
import sys
from pygame.locals import *

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

pygame.init()

pygame.display.set_caption("Neverout")
player = pygame.image.load("player.png")

green = (164, 164, 164)

WINDOW_SIZE = (1200, 700)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(WINDOW_SIZE, 0, 32)

wall_rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 1200, 50)
wall_rect2 = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 50, 1200)
wall_rect3 = pygame.Rect(50, 650, 450, 50)
wall_rect4 = pygame.Rect(1150, 0, 50, 700)
wall_rect5 = pygame.Rect(700, 650, 750, 50)

wall_list = [wall_rect, wall_rect2, wall_rect3, wall_rect4, wall_rect5]

player_pos = [385, 385]

while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    prev_pos = player_pos[:] 
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        player_pos[0] -= 8
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        player_pos[0] += 8
    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        player_pos[1] -= 8
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        player_pos[1] += 8

    plyer_rect = player.get_rect(topleft = player_pos)
    if any(plyer_rect.colliderect(w) for w in wall_list):
        player_pos = prev_pos  

    pygame.display.update()
    screen.fill(green)
    screen.blit(player, player_pos)
    for w in wall_list:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (230, 218, 0), w)
    clock.tick(60)
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUSH. I DON'T KNOW. THIS IS AWESOME. THANKS

Comment: did everything that it said)))))) Thank you!